# cytoscape.js elements disappear when using Firefox to zoom in or out

Tags: firefox, canvas, cytoscape.js

Using Firefox 24.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, I can reproduce this by:

1. Going to http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/ with Firefox
2. Use Ctrl + + or Ctrl + - to zoom in or out
3. Move the mouse over the graph in the corner and watch it disappear.

Seems to work fine in Chrome. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I can confirm this bug also occurs with Firefox 24.0 on Windows 7 Professional. I also tested on Firefox 19.0 running on Windows server 2008 R2 and I do NOT see this issue. It renders just fine in the older version of firefox. A colleague has Firefox 4.0 and it also renders correctly. This appears to be a rather annoying issue with the latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The same version of Firefox on Mac does not have this issue, leading me to believe this is a Firefox problem or an Ubuntu problem.  If I were you, I would file a bug report with Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

They can investigate whether this is an issue on their end or whether this is an issue on the Ubuntu end. -M

Comment: I've investigated, and found that Firefox incorrectly reports window.devicePixelRatio when you use the browser page zoom function. Please file a bug report with Firefox, as this is not a cy.js bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. In Firefox if you press <kbd>ctrl-0</kbd>, it will reset your zoom level to default. This appears to solve the bug in Firefox 24 and 25. If you then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in or out, the disappearing behavior will return. You can resolve again by resetting to default zoom level.

Not ideal behavior, but this is probably either a Firefox bug or a `cytoscape.js` bug.

Comment: I added the following issue ticket on the cytoscape.js github page, check there for more information: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/372

Comment: I've investigated, and found that Firefox incorrectly reports window.devicePixelRatio when you use the browser page zoom function. Please file a bug report with Firefox, as this is not a cy.js bug.