# chrome, cy.js 2.1.0: nodes disappear with mouse motion

Tags: cytoscape.js

macos 10.7.5
chrome Version 32.0.1700.107
Version 32.0.1700.107

and the simple "single.html" helpfully provided by gcpdev:

[live code examples: cytoscape.js initialization -- incomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650711/live-code-examples-cytoscape-js-initialization-incomplete)

Any movement by the mouse in the canvas makes the nodes disappear.  zooming and and out (with middle mouse roller button, for instance) makes them visible.

This problem is only on Chrome.  Firefox and Safari work fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

- Paul Shannon

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on Mac OS 10.9 with Chrome 32, which probably indicates this is a problem with Chrome rendering canvas on that version of Mac OS.

I notice that the linked demo is using v2.0.2.  Have you tried an updated v2.0.x release or v2.1.0?

Comment: I have upgraded my OS (to Mountaion Lion), upgraded chrome ( 33.0.1750.149) disabled all extensions, reset to browser defaults and yet still have the mouse-motion-canvas-contents-disappear problem.  reading https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/372 I got clued into browser zoom.  I don't use any zoom for cy.js, but if I DO, at large zooms, the network no longer disappears.  It's too zoomed in to view reasonably, but it works!  Maybe this could be a clue to you Max?  It's beyond my competence, for sure.   I would love to be able to use chrome....

Answer (score 0):

Try using pinch-zoom to set the zoom level for the webpage (not for the Cytoscape canvas element, which has its own separate zooming operated by scrolling with two fingers on the trackpad) to 100%. This fixed it for me, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992398/cytoscape-js-elements-disappear-when-using-firefox-to-zoom-in-or-out) question and [this](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/372) github issue, both about an almost identical issue in Firefox.